# Algorithmically generating all valid expressions

Tags: algorithm, expression, code-generation, combinatorics

Let's say I have some unary operations (negate, bitwise not, etc...), some binary operations (subtract, add, multiply, divide, bit shift, etc...), one possible operand (we'll say the operand must be the number `1`), and allow grouping by parentheses. Is there a way to generate all valid expressions (and *only* valid expressions) of a given length which can be created using these operators?

For instance, let's say I want all expressions of 4 characters. The following might be a subset of the generated list:

```cpp
    (-1)
    -1*1
    ~(1)
    ~-~1
    // etc...
```

Some 7 character expressions:

```cpp
    (1+1)<<1 // let's assume bitshifting is 1 character, since it's 1 operation.
    1/(1>>1) // expressions which fail to be evaluated (1/0) are fine, as long as they can be parsed.
    -~(1-1)
    // etc...
```

An example of a longer expression to show some complexity in grouping:

```cpp
    ((1<<(1+1+1))*(1+1))/((1<<(1+1))+1)
```

Comment: Generate parse trees. It is more or less trivial. Just use a proper multilevel expression grammar rather than relying on operator precedence, otherwise it is difficult to weed out trees like `+ 2 (* 3 4)` (here parens group tree branches rather than represent your source level parens).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks. Parse trees is the phrase I was looking for to get my brain going down the right path.

Comment: Oh and you need to make sure that the generator terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bootstrap the process by first concentrating on producing expressions that only consist of an operand with zero or more wrapped parentheses.

Here is a generator (in JavaScript syntax) that yields valid expressions with that limitation in mind:

```js
const operands = ["1"];

function* generateOperands(n) { // n is the size of the strings to generate
    if (n < 1) return;
    for (let operand of operands) {
        if (operand.length === n) {
            yield operand;
        }
    }
    // Use recursion to add a pair of parentheses:
    for (let operand of generateOperands(n - 2)) {
        yield "(" + operand + ")";
    }
}
```

NB: If you're not happy with the `yield` syntax, then just replace that with a push of the expression in some result array, or call a callback with that expression as argument.

Now extend this to use unary operators:

```js
const operands = ["1"];
const unaries = ["!", "~", "-"];

function* generateOperands(n) {
    if (n < 1) return;
    for (let operand of operands) {
        if (operand.length === n) {
            yield operand;
        }
    }
    for (let operand of generateOperands(n - 2)) {
        yield "(" + operand + ")";
    }
}

function* generateUnary(n) {
    yield* generateOperands(n);
    if (n < 2) return;
    for (let unary of unaries) {
        for (let expression of generateUnary(n - unary.length)) {
            yield unary + expression;
        }
        for (let expression of generateUnary(n - unary.length - 2)) {
            yield "(" + unary + expression + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

And finally add the possibility to include binary operator(s). Use the idea of the following recursive grammar:

```
expression := unary-expression [binary-operator expression]
```

...with this runnable code:

```js
const operands = ["1"];
const unaries = ["!", "~", "-"];
const binaries = ["-", "+", "*", "/", ">>", "<<"];

function* generateOperands(n) {
    if (n < 1) return;
    for (let operand of operands) {
        if (operand.length === n) {
            yield operand;
        }
    }
    for (let operand of generateOperands(n - 2)) {
        yield "(" + operand + ")";
    }
}

function* generateUnary(n) {
    yield* generateOperands(n);
    if (n < 2) return;
    for (let unary of unaries) {
        for (let expression of generateUnary(n - unary.length)) {
            yield unary + expression;
        }
        for (let expression of generateUnary(n - unary.length - 2)) {
            yield "(" + unary + expression + ")";
        }
    }
}

function* generate(n) {
    yield* generateUnary(n);
    if (n < 3) return;
    for (let binary of binaries) {
        for (let i = 1; i < n - binary.length; i++) {
            for (let left of generateUnary(i)) {
                for (let right of generate(n - i - binary.length)) {
                    yield left + binary + right;
                }
            }
            for (let left of generateUnary(i - 2)) {
                for (let right of generate(n - i - binary.length)) {
                    yield "(" + left + binary + right + ")";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Demo
for (let expression of generate(4)) {
    console.log(expression);
}
```